# Show computername, powershell version and remoting protocol

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a short script to show all computers powershell version and remoteing protocol. I am trying to get the output to look like

```
PC: PC1 ---------- PS:4.0------------Remoting Protocol: 2.2
PC: PC2 ---------- PS:3.0------------Remoting Protocol: 2.2
```

The PC names are stored in a file. So far I have tried the code below but couldn't figure out how to show the remoteing protocol or the PC name in a linear fashion

```
 cls
 $1 = (gc .\computers)
 invoke-command -computername $1 {$psversiontable.PSVersion.major}
 # this only gives me the PS version
```

Any suggestions / help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
Get-Content .\computers | ForEach-Object {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
    $fmt = 'PC: {0} ---------- PS:{1}.{2} ------------Remoting Protocol: {3}.{4}'

    $ps       = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
    $remoting = $PSVersionTable.PSRemotingProtocolVersion

    $fmt -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $ps.Major, $ps.Minor, $remoting.Major, $remoting.Minor
  }
}
```

Comment: Says its missing a few parenthesis

Comment: @NebelzCheez I doubt that. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Sorry about that! I added an extra string while copying the code. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Computers.txt
foreach ($c in $Computers)
{
    $winRMVersion = (test-wsman).ProductVersion.Split(':')[-1].Trim()
    $psVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
    "$c ---------- PS:$psVersion ------------Remoting Protocol: $winRMVersion"
}
```

Comment: ( $c in $computers ) comes underlined ? Says its incorrect